# Accessing values in textboxes dynamically created by jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I dynamically created textboxes using jQuery which are filled with random numbers. I am not sure how to access the values inside the dynamically created textboxes. 
I want to access the textbox values so I can test them for duplicate numbers or to check if they are nonnumeric since the user can change and enter any character into the textboxes
after they are created. I probably cannot use an array to access them since I won't be able to test the values using the jQuery Validate plugin (or can I?) before they are inserted 
into MySQL using PHP. Also, I would like access to the textbox values so they can be inserted into MySQL using PHP. Does anyone have any idea how I can access the textbox values of 
these dynamically created textboxes so they can be referred to using PHP for insertion into MySQL? Thanks much for any help.

This is the main code which creates the dynamic textboxes and inputs the random numbers.

```
    // Fill the textboxes with the generated numbers
    var parentForm = $(this).closest(".form");
    for (var n in random_numbers)
    parentForm.find(".inputs input:eq(" + n + ")").val(random_numbers[n]);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdownadd').change(function() {

        var dropDownDiv = $('#dropdowndiv');

        dropDownDiv.html("");

        $loopcount = $(this).val();

        for (var i = 1; i <= $loopcount; i++) {
            var setHtml = "";

            setHtml = '<div class="form"><form id="frm' + i + '">';
            setHtml += '<label>Number Set #' + i + '</label>';
            setHtml += '<div class="action"><input type="button" class="button" id="btn' + i + '" value="Generate Numbers" /></div>';
            setHtml += '<div class="inputs">';
            for (var t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
                setHtml += '<input type="text" name="num' + t + '" id="num' + t + '" class="input" />';
            }
            setHtml += '</div>';
            setHtml += '</div>';
            dropDownDiv.append(setHtml);

            $("#btn" + i).bind('randomize', getRandomNumbers).click(function(e) {
                $(this).trigger('randomize');
            });
        }
```

Comment: will provide a jQuery validate solution but first do you really want individual forms for each row?

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, each row doesn't need to be an individual form. I'm most interested in how to access the textbox values so PHP is used to insert those values into MySQL. Once the textboxes are dynamically created and filled with values, a user can change those values inside the textbox. Another issue would be how to account for the number of dynamically created textboxes since the current options available in the dropdown menu is 1,2,3,5 and 12. So, the maximum number of textboxes created would be 36. One solution would be to hard code in PHP 36 inputs. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: I worked on this quite a bit and have the UI being validated by validation plugin. New random number generator- old one was creating 10,000 numbers for each input and took a while. Mine checks duplicates as it generates them. Some minor html changes, all in one form now. Main issue is I'm not 100% sure how this will be used. Help if you play with it a bit. Code needs some refactoring but seems to work fine for what I think it should do  http://jsfiddle.net/P7xuV/ Also for php...not sure what you will do with these numbers when stored, so not sure what best format to store them is.

Comment: basically I can help, I like these little apps, but would help to understand usage better to help refine code

Comment: To be honest, the tools (MVVM) are out there in order to make things like this a whole lot easier these days. i.e. http://www.knockoutjs.com. That'll make your code a lot easier to work with in this scenario.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, thank you for the information. I will examine it more closely. Does this site allow people to contact others for more information? If so, what is your email or you can find my email listed on my profile. Anyway, I am not sure if you code will allow access with PHP for MySQL insertion. I think it has some glitches in it still. I will need to look at it more. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: as far as php goes that is no problem , it's just a matter of how you want to be able to use the data from db. Can serialize it all in one field if want to, or split it into numerous fields. Again help to understand what will be used for. looping over `$_GET` or $_POST` to manipulate into any storage format you want is not hard

Comment: here's revised version with refresh and reset working and only row duplicates checked  http://jsfiddle.net/P7xuV/2/

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, using some jQuery I can generate this data >> num_1_0=175427,num_1_1=603844,num_1_2=627923,num_2_0=539060,num_2_1=608926,num_2_2=628206 on the webpage but it is outside your div wrapper and it won't be picked up by PHP still. I am still trying to get it to work with the $_GET but it won't work. At least, I have some data now. I just need to find how to get it working with the PHP file. I am trying to get it in the div wrapper but no working yet. Thank you for your help.

Comment: perhaps you still have `debug: true,` in validation options... that will stop form submit for testing such as in fiddle. No idea what you mean by `outside of div` . Inspect the elements in a browser console, they should all be inside the form

Comment: I made a new div for testing some new jQuery code, that's what I mean. I get some data now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, maybe you will know the answer, I tried to insert into MySQL using this (the format works in a normal MySQL insert but not here) but it is not working, any idea why it doesn't work? Thank you. I used echo '<pre>'; $theArray=($_POST);
print_r($theArray); $sql= sprintf('INSERT INTO $tbl_name (%s) VALUES (%s)', implode(', ',array_keys($theArray)), implode(', ',array_values($theArray))); All the fields are VARCHAR in the db
$result=mysql_query($sql);

Comment: check mysql errors also try outputting the statement to see that it looks like.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, there are no MySQL errors and the output looks good. I tested the same output using the usual MySQL insert from forms and those inserted but using the above INSERT is not working and I can't find the cause yet. The output is exactly what I used in the normal INSERT and those worked.

Comment: not sure what to tell you... is very difficult to troubleshoot every step for you remotely

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I have the output correct but it won't insert into the db. I don't know why. Did you have any success in inserting it into MySQL? Thank you.

Comment: can't have insert fail and no error

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically create the textboxes give them both an unique **id** tag and a **name** tag (same values)

For example TB1 TB2 TB3....

You'll then be able to access them from JS with

```
$('#TB' + n).val()
```

where **n** is the text box number you want to access.

As they are in a form, the values will be posted to the speciefied form url in the tag **action** and will be available for processing with PHP

Comment: OP is already doing what you suggest, however it lacks method to prevent duplicating ID's across forms. Selector you are using is invalid (missing prefix)

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, in your code is the array you are pulling data from using PHP called updateMasterNumbersArray()? Your code disabled the "Refresh all sets" button function for some reason. Also, your check function of duplicate values is occurring with all the textbox fields in every number set and checking for duplication. What I was seeking was to check each number set of 3 numbers individually and not checking against the other number sets. Each set of 3 numbers are checked for duplicates but not against the other number sets. Is that possible to do? Thanks much.

Comment: ahhh.. wish I'd known about only check row for duplicates. That is so much easier and will cut out  a bunch of my code. As for php , the javascript you see has nothing to do with php. The only php I've used is `print_r($_GET)` in a file that is the action for form. I'll revise the duplicate checks to just rows and fix the validation to match. Also will fix the reset

Comment: Hi, @charlietfl, were you able to make the changes so each set (or row) of textboxes can be checked for duplicate numbers if the user changes them and making the reset function again? Do you know how to add a button dynamically for each set of textboxes (row) to clear the textboxes and allow for new numbers to be generated in them? Also, can you provide your PHP code for how you submit the textbox fields for inserting into MySQL? My PHP code does not seem to be working. Thanks much.

Comment: @Lynn yes...posted in last comment under question serveral days ago

Comment: Hello @charlietfl, sorry but I still don't get your array values. 
1. Do you have the <pre> tag somewhere in your HTML or is that not necessary? 
2. Can I send you my code or you send me yours or post the code on JSFiddle where you have the process-form.php working? Maybe, you added something else to the code.
3. I tried many variations and changes in process-form.php and the file with the HTML/javascript but I don't get the array you are getting from the PHP file. I get empty arrays only. I have previously sent data from textboxes in HTML to MySQL using PHP but I can't get it to work here.

Comment: Hello @charlietfl 
4. I agree with you and added the action and method such as the following but it isn't working. 
<div id="dropdowndiv">
            <form id="numbers_form" method="post" action="processform.php">
   <button>Send to PHP</button> //I added this button to test
            <!-- this is where textboxes will appear -->
 </div>
5. My process-form.php is the same as yours.
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET); 
?>
6. I read everything you wrote several times and did exactly as you wrote. Can you send me your working code files my email is lyndta@gmail.com Thank you very much.

Comment: why the button? There's already a submit button in the dynamic form contents. Also check console for any errors

Comment: The button was just for testing @charlietfl, check which console? The submit button is dynamically generate, yes? I tried that submit button and putting the action and method inside the javascript, too. So far, I can't get the same array values as you. I only get empty arrays. Did you put <pre></pre> anywhere in the HTML? Maybe, you added other code that is not in the JSFiddle. I tried many many variations and I cannot get the same array output as you using the process-form.php file. I don't know why. Can you send me your working code files? I don't see any errors anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I used your github & JSFiddle files but I still get no array like you showed. When I click submit I get nothing returned. I was testing with buttons and moving things around but I just get empty arrays and no array has returned the textbox numbers yet. Are you using the exact same javascript as you have posted on JSFiddle or did you make some changes? I get no errors in PHP or in Apache logs. Are you able to insert the numbers into MySQL? I tried it on two PCs using WAMP and XAMPP and still nothing. Would you have any other suggestions or what I can try? This should work.

Comment: those files work perfectly on my machine, assuming you have jquery in correct path and I had used a file tst.js with exact same code in it

Answer (score 0):

Based on demo I created here is how I am receiving form currently in php:

```
print_r( $_GET);
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [num_1_0] => 385122
    [num_1_1] => 719388
    [num_1_2] => 865862
    [num_2_0] => 205449
    [num_2_1] => 819047
    [num_2_2] => 870961
)
```

Can easily manipulate this array into any other format. First digit in field name is row, second is index in row

**EDIT** : To visualize this output set form method to "GET" , set action to `process-form.php`. In `process-form.php` put following:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $_GET);
```

Now submit form

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, it is good. This will also work with $_POST in PHP? How are you accessing the array data using PHP to get this array? Is it in the same file? What is the name of the array you are retrieving the values from? Are you using a separate PHP file to access the array? Thanks much.

Comment: receive as would any other form using `$_GET` or `$_POST`. I used GET so could print the array in a new page as shown using `print_r`

Comment: inspect the `input` elements created in a browser console will see that the `name` and `id` matches array above. Example: `num_1_0`. Parse the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array in php ( example array shown in this answer) to do whatever you want with the individual values. You have never explained what you will do with them later, or what format you want them stored in.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, can you post your entire PHP code please? The individual values should be just numbers and I would simply like to insert those numbers into a MySQL db. Because the textboxes are dynamically generated the MySQL db table should have the maximum number of field to fit the maximum numbers in this case 36 fields (options max is 12 x 3 textboxes per generated set). The format would Int and Length is 7. Do you understand now? Please post your entire PHP code so I can see how you accessed the individual values from the dynamically generated textboxes. Thank you very much.

Comment: I posted all the php I used. I only created a simple dump of `$_GET` to show you what the array looks like. I added that code to answer earlier today. If you are going to put each value in an individual field in db, can make the field names match the naming protocol I started and updating db will be easy. A simple loop over the request and check that field name has string `num_` in it

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, is this what you did for the last 3 lines $numForm.append(globalRefresh); $numForm.append('<div class="submit_row"><form><input type="submit" value="Submit Numbers" method="GET" action="process-form.php"/></form></div>');
$numForm.validate(validationOptions); and then in process-form.php you have <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r( $_GET); ?> Where did you put the <pre> and </pre> and I am not sure which form you put the method="GET" action="process-form.php" Can you chat on Skype or Gmail please? Did you get it to store in MySQL? I am still trying. Thank you very much.

Comment: close... `action` and `method` are form properties to tell form where and how to submit   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp. You should probably find some tutorials on forms submit and php

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, yes, I know about form attributes and PHP, but in this situation the textboxes are dynamically created. Ok, just tell me where you are placing the <pre></pre> tags and where you are placing the method="GET" action="process-form.php" Where in the JSFiddle code are you placing those? Maybe, you can add them as comment lines or tell me the line number in the code. That is where I am confused about how you are accessing the textbox values. That is the only confusion I am having now. Are you adding a new form like <form type="submit", method="GET" action="process-form.php">?

Comment: look at bottom of the html, not script `<form id="numbers_form">`. The only thing needed to make it submit is the action and method. The fiddle can only work with javascript...  please reread the **Edit** part of answer above about php. You need to create that file

Comment: Hi, @charlietfl, the jQuery is working since I get numbers. The PHP seems to work when I put buttons or change the form location but I get empty arrays. When I have no extra buttons and no extra code, I click submit and nothing happens. How is your PC set up? I tried the code many times with the same nothing result with the array in PHP. I like your method and it should work. I can't figure out why it does not work. Is another way to access the textbox values I could try? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @charlietfl, this jQuery code produces repeated sets of (num0, num1, and num2) for each set of numbers. If you selected 3 sets of forms you would get 3 sets of (num0, num1, and num2). What I wanted for the selected 3 sets would be (num0, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8 and num9). Each numX could be inserted into MySQL with PHP. Is that possible to do? Thank you.

$('<button/>',{'id':'submit'}).text('SUBMIT').appendTo( 'body' );
$(document).on('click','#submit',function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        alert( $(this).serialize() );
    });
});

Comment: you must be using a different version of the javascript than I used. Mine produces sequence shown in above answer, there are no duplications of field names

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I was trying a different way to access the textbox values since I cannot get the same PHP array output as you for some reason. I even used your code and still I got no array like yours. What is your PC setup? This should work since I have used PHP with javascript on this PC. So, now I am trying to see if I can get the values in a different way, thus I changed the javascript as shown above to do that. I don't know why I cannot get the arrays that you got. Any ideas? Are you using the code on JSFiddle? Did you make any changes which you forgot about? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: if you use GET to test( w/o AJAX), should see all the values in URL. You have all the code I used, I can't explain what would be different. It is a simple form submit